# Can a simple program that runs in the java IDE client console be an executable file?

Tags: java, console, exe

**Can a simple program that runs in the java IDE client console be an executable file?**

for example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.print("HI");
}
```

Would appear in the console when exported as a runnable jar file. Will it be able to run as an executable file after using launch4j?

Comment: You can convert java programs to exe. For example by using Intellij IDE.

Comment: even those that areonly found in the IDE's console?

Answer (score 3):

You will get an .exe file, but it will just launch the JAR automatically. So you will still have to have a JRE installed in order to run the .exe.

Comment: but if the code uses jframe jpanel etc will the .exe run as an .exe?

Comment: @user2277371 A program written in Java is always a Java program. You compile Java source to `.class` files, bytecode for the Java Virtual Machine. As far as I know, every `.exe` you can make out of Java programs still requires a Java Runtime Environment on the client computer. Frames or no frames, it doesn't make much of a difference, in regards to this topic.

Comment: do .class files run the same way as .exe files?

Comment: @user2277371 I'm not sure of what you mean by *running the same way*, but I'd say the answer is no. A `.exe` is an executable file, it is native binary code that the operating system and the hardware understand. On the other hand, a `.class` file is code that the Java Virtual Machine may load and execute. Your operating system cannot launch such program. It can only launch the JVM, which, in turn, launches the Java program. That's more or less what the `.exe`s you make out of JARs do.